# Securing my post requests without SSL

Tags: php, ios, security, post, ssl

I have an app (iOS) which is sending post requests to a server, where the data is checked and stored. Basically I'm sending a userid, latitude and longitude values. On my server there is a simple php script which does some basic checks and saves the data into a database.

This means if I'm on wifi with my phone and somebody does packet sniffing, he could just reuse or change these values and flood my server with wrong data. Is there some nice way of avoiding this? I'm not really that much into these kinds of security things and using SSL seemed to be a bit of an overkill for my purpose. I was thinking about some sort of additional post value which I'd validate on the server and then decide if the request is valid or not, but I couldn't find any simple way to accomplish something like that.

Any thoughts on that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you're worried about packet sniffing, then there's nothing you can do to prevent that sniffling EXCEPT for using SSL. What's the point of embedding a special value in your request when those requests are being sniffed. It's like you're stripping naked in the middle of a crowded area and then going "don't look at me!" and wondering why your nekkid pics are showing up on the news. Just switch your requests over to ssl and bye-bye goes the sniffing problem.

Comment: Passphrase. Prior to the Sending of the Data; you'd receive some random string from the server, which you would append to the passphrase you enter in your app, then hash it, send it off to the server, Server would run the same check; Passphrase+LastRandomSalt>Hashed=Received then save to database. Since the received value is not likely to be repeated, the Packet Sniffer would only get that one-use token.

Comment: "using SSL seemed to be a bit of an overkill for my purpose" - No. In fact, you can get SSL certificates for free from StartSSL, etc. so there's really no excuse not to use HTTPS

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have decided to use SSL. Figured it out pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSL is definitely a perfect match here, since you don't want attackers to know what is written in your packet.
You could also add a timestamp to avoid TCP replay attacks, and a login / password tuple to ensure that the device sending these information is authorized to do so for a specific user.

Comment: I decided to use SSL and it already works. I'm using a self-signed Certificate though. Could you please explain what you meant with adding a timestamp to avoid TCP replay attacks? I guess you mean just adding another POST-variable containing the current timestamp of the device, but how do I validate this on the server then?

Comment: Yes exactly. If you allow your clients to send data which is timestamped and the time difference between the server and the client is greater than 5 minutes for example, you could safely discard any "alien" message not matching the timeframe. (see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) )

Comment: Ok, I understand. But this wouldn't block Replay Attacks if they were sent within the same timeframe, right?

Comment: @gasparuff indeed, it's the poor man's protection. There are better ways to implement that (OTP, tokens, nonce, you name it) but these require more efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a Session-based passphrase. The implementation will differ hugely whether you're the only user or one of multiple. Everytime you want to submit new data to the server, request a PHRASE from the server, which will be a randomly generated string; it has to be stored on the server, if multiple users then tied to that SESSION/USER. Your app will have to then take some form of input from you; like a PIN CODE or a Password, which will get salted with this PHRASE, then hashed. The hashed value will get sent along side your other values [Lat, Lng, ...] and the same comparison will be made on the server, which will have the salted Password+Phrase [or multiple if multiple passwords will co-exist] if it matches then allow the submission of data, else disallow it. The packet sniffer would be able to sniff your packets but unless that Randomly Generated Phrase ever repeats itself their findings would be completely useless as this forces a single-use-style-token. This prevents TCP Replay Attacks also as the data would be regarded as incorrect, as the token would be incorrect after the first submission [which would obviously reset the Phrase stored on the server/generate a new one]

The transformation/hash you use to change the password salted with the phrase has to be one-way so the Packet Sniffer is not unable to undo it and get at your PIN/Password.

Edit, or as others have said use SSL; the above is probably good etiquette for use with SSL but will work properly without it. ++ I know the Lat, Lng, ... etc will be still be able to be sniffed, but considering they're on the same wi-fi; I doubt they're that very much different from the attackers. Plus it wasn't the problem at hand in the OP.